# Return a value from json in Google Sheets script editor

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a value from a json object from a URL for use in a Google Sheet.

This is the script:

```js
function ccprice()
{
var url = "https://acx.io//api/v2/tickers/btcaud.json"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);

var price = data.buy
                                    
return price
}
```

When I call the function in Google Sheet, it has an error:

Error
Unknown range name: 'CCPRICE'

Comment: How are you invoking a function? Please post your problem in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON data is as follows.

```
{
  "at": ###,
  "ticker": {
    "buy": ###,
    "sell": ###,
    "low": ###,
    "high": ###,
    "last": ###,
    "vol": ###
  }
}
```

If you need the value for the key of `buy`, how about a change as follows?

**From :**

```
var price = data.buy
```

**To :**

```
var price = data.ticker.buy
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly calling it as a function?

```
=ccprice()
```